# Plesk server external POP connection

Tags: wordpress, plesk, pop3

I have Bounce Email feature of MailPoet plugin of Wordpress. All is set up correctly but when I push Try to connect it times out. The MailPoet support is saying “That error comes from your webserver. It seems that your server doesn't allow external POP connections.” 
So PLESK server doesn't allow external POP connection.
The question is - where to set it - I tried almost everything in Tools and Settings -> Mail Settings

Answer (score 0):

In Plesk, go to Tools and Settings > Services Management. Make sure the courier-imap or dovecot services are running. If not, start them.

If it does not work, make sure POP3 connections are allowed on a firewall level: if a firewall blocks 110 or 995 (for secured POP3), then the external connection will not be possible. The fastest way to check it is installing Firewall extension in Plesk, enabling it and opening 110 and 995 ports.

Comment: Thanks for reply but it didn't help. Firewall was installed and all but "System policy for incoming traffic" and "System policy for forwarding of traffic" were allowed. I switched those 2 to allowed and the error is the same 
"Request error not JSON:<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>